# Подгрузка новых сообщений из бд

Tags: ajax, php, mysql

**Добрый день!** Друзья, у меня стоит задача: **автоматически подгружать новые сообщения из бд**. Есть идея как это сделать (**через, допустим, 3 секунды посылать Ajax запрос php скрипту, что бы тот в свою очередь проверял есть ли новый сообщения и выводил их**). 
Но, как я считаю данный способ будет сильно нагружать сервер. Если я прав, то натолкните как можно ещё решить данную задачу, но что бы не нагружать сервер.

Comment: выводи через 10 секунд, на сколько актуальными они должны быть?

Comment: @Shrek, всё равно делать каждые 10 секунд запрос для каждого пользователя как то напряжно для сервера.

Comment: Посылать запрос на вывод новых сообщений тогда когда кто-то из участников диалога нажал кнопку send.

Comment: @Palmervan, т.e. подгружать только тому кто отправил?

Comment: Увеличить время. Если пользователь нажал какие то кнопки значит выполнить проверку на новые сообщения. Следующая проверка через 5 сек. Следующая через 15 сек -> 30 -> 80 -> 120 и.т.д. 

Соответственно массив с временем последней проверки для каждого пользователя можно вообще не в базе хранить, а сразу в памяти.

Comment: Как вы определили то, что запрос каждые 10 секунд это накладно для вашего сервера? вы тесты писали?

Comment: @AlexWindHope, я не определял. При том, сервера даже не видел (он не мой а заказчика), но как мне сообщили он очень медленный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не хотите нагружать сервер, напишите небольшую программку на C, С++, Go etc которая будет слушать любой свободный порт и возвращать список комментариев. 
Ну и соответственно запросы шлите уже ей напрямую. Это позволит не создавать лишней нагрузки на сервер, при этом не ограничивая себя особо. Правда у такого подхода есть и минусы:

1. Простой хостинг не подойдет, нужен сервер
2. За программкой придется присматривать, если вдруг она упадет, обновления работать не будут

А в остальном сплошные плюсы )))